# Curves with distance between them growing locally as $o(d^k)$

Tags: differential-geometry

**Context**: I'm searching for some standard definitions related to order of contact between curves (and smooth manifolds in general).

My research has taken me to the concept of [jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics)). Simply speaking, a $k$-jet is a class of functions with all same derivatives up to $k$-th order. Same concept of jets is defined for functions $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{M}$ representing curves on a smooth manifold $\mathcal{M}$ (some abstract things are added in the [wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics)#Jets_of_functions_from_the_real_line_to_a_manifold) though).

However, considering $k$-jets of curves on a manifold is not a good idea. In fact, $1$-jets of naturally-parametrized curves passing through a point correspond to tangents at that point. But everything breaks when looking at $2$-jets.

Consider two curves $A(t) = (t, t^2)$ and $B(t) = (t + t^2, t^2)$ on a 2D plane. As far as I understand it, they belong to two different $2$-jets. However, if we reparametrize $B(t)$ as $B(s)$ with $s = t + t^2$, then $A(t)$ and $B(s)$ would belong to the same $2$-jet. So jets are parametrization-dependent.

Is there are similar concept which defines equivalence classes on curves which are sufficiently close to each other locally?

Intuitively, I'd like to consider two curves passing through point $P$ equivalent up to order $k$ when the distance between them grows as $o(d^k)$, where $d$ is distance between $P$ and the location considered. E.g. a line and a touching circle are equivalent up to order $1$, but not up to order $2$. $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are equivalent up to order $2$.